# How to solve error: "Clock skew detected"?

Tags: makefile, clock

I am uploading my OpenCL and Cuda code to [hgpu.org](http://hgpu.org) because I don't have a graphics card on my laptop. When I upload my code I get the following error:

```
make: Warning: File `main.cu' has modification time 381 s in the future
make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
```

I know that clock skew is due to difference in my machines clock time and the server's clock time, so I synchronized my time with the server's. The OpenCL and C++ code is running fine now but the Cuda code is still giving me this error.

So my question is:

**Is there any other reason for clock skew error besides the time synchronization? And if there is then how do I solve it?**

Cuda Code:

```
__global__
void test()
{
}

int main()
{
    dim3 gridblock(1,1,1);
    dim3 threadblock(1,1,1);

    test<<<gridblock,threadblock>>>();
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I can provide the make file too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question.

I added the following lines of code to my Makefile and it fixed the "clock skew" problem:

```
clean:  
    find . -type f | xargs touch
    rm -rf $(OBJS)
```

Comment: This only treats the symptom and not the underlaying cause, it doesn't "fix" the problem. If someone else has this problem, please don't do this!

Comment: @RolKau What do you think the problem is?

Answer (score 10):

Simply go to the directory where the troubling file is, type `touch *` without quotes in the console, and you should be good.

Comment: And update the timestamps of all the files in that directory ? Isn't that a bit dangerous, especially if accidentally done in the wrong directory ?

Answer (score 7):

One of the reason may be improper date/time of your PC.

In Ubuntu PC to check the date and time using:

```sh
date
```

Example, One of the ways to update date and time is:

```sh
date -s "23 MAR 2017 17:06:00"
```

Comment: match this situation,  correct system time, problem resolved. : )

Answer (score 2):

please try to do

```
make clean
```

(instead of `make`), then

```
make
```

again.