# Syncing time, date and time-zone with an embedded Linux machine

Tags: c++, linux

I have an embedded system that runs Ubuntu 14 and is connected to my laptop through an Ethernet cable. I am trying to sync the time/date/timezone of the board with my laptop. The board does not have any Internet connectivity and I can not run `ntp` like `ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com`.

What I have in mind is to get the time/date/time-zone of my laptop using a C++ code like [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/system_clock/) and then run `date --set=<laptop_time_date>` [command](https://superuser.com/questions/302396/how-to-set-current-time-on-linux) on the remote board (using a remote SSH connection). Is this the correct way to do this? and how to syn the time zones too?

P.S. The reason I need to sync the time/date of the board with my laptop is to let `make` to work properly. I copy multiple source files through SSH connection to the board and then call make to build the program. make produces a warning that timestamp of file is in the future. One way to solve this is to call [touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235654/how-to-solve-error-clock-skew-detected) on all the source files to update the time stamps, but it forces a rebuild.

Comment: Wouldn't be cross-compiling (once set up) easier?

Comment: If the embedded board runs Ubuntu, _why_ can't you run NTP or `ntpdate` on it?   Can you run `rdate` instead?

Comment: Try this `sudo date -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z"`